# Using Exec() on Apache on window platform

Tags: php, android, apache, exec

I am trying to run an exec placed on my server using android emulator. When i use exec() command through my local host the commands works fine ( i didnt change any permissions) . but when i am running same php file which has exec command using android emulator the exec() doesnot seem to work any advice ? How can i run run exe using php from android. Is it do able and any other solutions.

I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

> How can i run run exe using php from android.

Android is not Windows. Android does not run "EXE" files.

> any other solutions

You could write a regular Android SDK application, using Java, and not use PHP.

Or, you could write an HTML-based Android SDK application, using tools like PhoneGap, and not use PHP.

Or, you could write simple scripts in PHP via SL4A, though this is not designed for operation as a server.

Comment: you got my query wrong but now i am able to run exec() command . thanks for the help :)